# Sin conexión a Firebase por WIFI Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

tengo una aplicación en Java hecha en Android Studio e implementa firebase, funciona correctamente con los datos moviles, pero cuando me conecto por wifi (el cual funciona perfectamente) parece que no conecta con firebase, porque no me devuelve valores y tampoco puedo modificar datos (pasa lo mismo con los modems de conocidos).

Como dato curioso, si reinicio el modem y me conecto al wifi ya me permite leer y escribir datos en firebase.

Alguien tiene idea de que puede ser?

```
private void consultarCoins(String telefonoUsuario, final TextView tvCoin) {
    if (isNetworkConnected(MenuActivity.this) == true) {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference Ref = database.getReference(FirebaseReferences.CLIENTES_REFERENCE);
        ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ClienteFirebase post = dataSnapshot.getValue(ClienteFirebase.class);
                if (post != null) {
                    coin = post.getCoin();
                    tvCoin.setText("Coins: $" + coin);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){
                Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "error " + databaseError.toException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        Ref.child("" + telefonoUsuario).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(postListener);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No estas conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context
            .CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info == null || !info.isConnected() || !info.isAvailable()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Parece que el problema esta en la api de conexión pero sin un ejemplo es imposible orientarte. Podrías añadir un ejemplo de código que hallas utilizado? puedes hechar un vistazo a [Como preguntar ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: Con gusto te adjunto un ejemplo, pero que código es el que te gustaría revisar? no comprendo eso de la api de conexión... Saludos!

Comment: como te dije antes sin un ejemplo será imposible saber en que línea de código  reside este problema. No estaría mal ver como has implementado la conexión (aunque pongas datos falsos evidentemente) y accedes a los datos, puede que el problema esté en la implementación y no en los dispositivos no ?... saludos

Comment: He agregado un ejemplo solicitud de datos desde mi app a firebase, ejecutándolo así desde datos móviles funciona, pero si me conecto por wifi no me funciona. Espero éste código sea útil para encontrar el error. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Según he podido comprobar [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176428/5831897) algunos usuarios vuelven a comprobar el estado de la conexión  y lo devuelven como valor del `isNetworkConnected`. Espero que te sirva también.

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager == null) {
      return false;
    }

    NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    // vuelve a preguntar
    return info.isConnected();
}
```